# Beetle Identification - Oregon

Tags: species-identification, entomology

My dad found it so I don't have a lot of good information, but it was probably about 2.5 inches, somewhat west of Portland, and was found on a sidewalk. I don't know the area so I can't say what habitats are there that it might have come from.[image]

Comment: This is a long horned beetle.. currently trying to pinpoint genus and species.

Comment: I agree that overall appearance is very longhornish. However, I cannot get the shape of the pronotum to fit with the rest of the animal (when thinking about possible tribes/subfamilies) @Charles

Comment: Too bad that the tarsal formula cannot be seen in the picture, which could rule out several families.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this may be a male of [*Trichocnemis spiculatus*](http://cerambycidae.org/taxa/spiculatus-(LeConte-1851)) (Cerambycidae, subfamily [Prioninae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prioninae)). This species is known from Western USA/Oregon, based on this key: [Screening Aid for the Cerambycidae of the Western U.S.A.](https://caps.ceris.purdue.edu/webfm_send/2113) (from Oregon Department of Agriculture). By overall appearance, this species fits well. However, females have more pronounced spines at the sides of the pronotum, which points to a male for the individual in your picture.

[image]
(picture from http://cerambycidae.org/taxa/spiculatus-(LeConte-1851), also more pictures at [bugguide.net](http://bugguide.net/node/view/74268/bgpage))